# How to setup a local xampp behind my company's proxy

Tags: apache, curl, amazon-web-services, xampp, local

I am trying to do curl requests through my local xampp setup but my company has a firewall proxy that needs to authenticate on port 8080. Can I have apache login to this proxy authenticate and complete the curl requests?

Comment: BTW, I found out that this is not possible, globally, as of now. This bug explains the progress http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29280

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in your curl request

if for example you are coding in php

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://proxy");
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
```

You will probably need to use CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH as well

or you may want to try setting HTTP_PROXY ENV variable

Comment: This worked: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://proxy");curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "username:password"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);

Comment: How would I set the HTTP_PROXY ENV? Would this default all PHP outgoing request to use it?

Comment: In a XAMPP installation, you can set the HTTP_PROXY ENV variable in the ./apache/conf/extra/http-xampp.conf file by adding the following line inside an <IfModule env_module> block: SetEnv HTTP_PROXY "http://username:pass@serveraddress:portnumber"

Answer (score 0):

To set HTTP_PROXY

export http_proxy=http://proxy:8080/

Comment: How would I set the username and password? Btw this is a xampp setup on windows. Would I use htaccess? How?